# Calling function more than once causes gameplay issues in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I am currently working on translating a VR game to the Oculus Quest 2 from a PC standalone version. In this game, the game menu cannot be accessed by the player wearing the headset, as it is not visible to the player; it is instead accessed by another party at the computer itself. When the person at the computer clicks, start game, a number of processes begin, including a coroutine to spawn multiple instances of a game object in a non-player enemy's hands.

Part of the translation process includes allowing the player to start the game from the Oculus Touch controllers, I am attempting to implement a feature where either of the four face buttons will start the game.

```
 if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.One) || OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.Two) || OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.Three) || OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.Four))
         {
             startGameClick();
         }
```

However, it seems like calling `startGameClick();` more than once, whether in the same script or otherwise, causes the game to not run certain processes, chief among them the ball spawn coroutine. This causes the NPC enemies to activate their throwing animations without having a ball to throw, and they do not return to their idle animations afterwards. I am unsure why this is, however it has been a major roadblock in attempting the platform translation.

Additionally, this is the `startGameClick();` function:

```
// If the start game button is clicked
     public void startGameClick() {
         StandaloneServer.startgame = true;

         if (Master.usingMM && ServerController.IsServerReady())
             Master.ready = true;
         else if (!Master.usingMM)
             Master.ready = true;

         roundController.startInput();

         beginGameButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "In Progress";
         beginGameButton.interactable = false;
     }
```

My assumption is that one of the references in this function is the source of the issue, but I cannot pinpoint which one.

Comment: And you sure nothing anywhere else calls that code?

Comment: @BugFinder The issue isn't with what is calling the code, the issue is with the values that he is changing after startGameClick is initially called. He either needs to share all of his code so we can tell him exactly which values need to be reset or he should do it himself, or as I say in my answer, simply reload the scene and the values will reset to their default states.

Comment: @Displayname i semi disagree.  He states it’s running more than once. It could be that he’s calling an object that assigns this is adding to it for each reset. I agree there’s not enough info though

Comment: Nothing else in the code calls it, other than the other instance in which I call it, it is only called once.

Comment: @BugFinder Once again, as is backed up by Jason Arhin, the issue has nothing to do with what is calling it and everything to do with the variables that he changes after calling and does not revert to default when calling again. If we had the code, and a bit of compassion we could pick out the variables that need to be reset on game reset.

Answer (score 0):

### Base Information

Unfortunately, to answer your question, we would need to see all of the related scripts for this function which just isn't feasible as that would also require us to be kind enough to sift through your code to find your error.

### A Cheap Solution

However, there is a cheap solution to your issue. You can simply reload the scene (or reset the script if it's DNDOL) and it should work again.

Comment: Yeah it would make sense to add the rest of the code, the problem is that there is a lot of it as it is a massive project.

Comment: Well, you have some variables that are not being reset which breaks everything. If you don't want to (or are unable to) deal with that then your best bet might be to just call `UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);` Of course, this assumes that you're not using DoNotDestroyOnLoad ...in that case, you would have to destroy that object and create a new one. Yes it is roundabout ...but the only other option that I know of is to go through all of your code and reset the needed variables.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found a solution at long last.

Instead of calling the `startGame()` function again, I decided to invoke `onClick()` to simulate the effect of clicking the button with a mouse, although the player is actually touching the button in the VR space. This worked, and the game is running as it should.